# Swashbuckle: include a type to "definitions" section of swagger file

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a webapi in my application with action that can return some data. Data is described by type "CurrentTask" that has a property "Payload".

There are more that one type of task in my application and depending on the type payload prop can be in different shape, so in my contract it has type "object". Beside that I have classes for each type of payload and backend code mostly works with this classes rather that with object.

I think it'll be great to exapnd this experience to frontend part too. So I'm wondering if there is a way (applying attribute to payload class for example) to tell Swashbuckle to include this payload types to "definitions" section in swagger file.

Thanks for help!

Code snippets for better understanding:

```
class TaskController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Task<CurrentTask> Next()
    {

    }
}

class CurrentTask
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public object Payload { get; set; }
}

class Task1Payload
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class Task2Payload
{
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've done that, but not with an attribute instead using an IDocumentFilter: https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L581

Comment: Hi! Thanks for response. 
It seems that your solution allows filtering endpoints which are not supposed to be included to swagger file. In my case, there are types whitch don't participate in any endpoint, but have to be included to swagger file. Or I missed something? Could you provide a detailed example, please?

Comment: Look for ApplyDocumentVendorExtensions in the link I sent